# Windows 10 Enterprise edition returns product name as Windows 8 Pro

Tags: windows, windows-10, inno-setup

I am having a Windows 10 Enterprise Evaluation VM and when I navigated the registry to find the Product name under `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion` `ProductName`, I found it was **Windows 10 Enterprise Evaluation**.

I used innosetup function to print the product name in my code using the below function.

```
RegQueryStringValue(HKLM64, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion', 'ProductName', strProductName)
```

where `strProductName` is a String variable I used in the function, but it prints **Windows 8 Pro**.

Any idea as to what was the problem.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Windows lies to you about the actual version. See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38102565/how-can-a-vb-6-app-determine-if-it-is-running-on-windows-10) discussing the problem in relation to VB 6. The problem is similar, no matter which language you're using, since you're calling the same OS API. You either need a manifest that marks your app (in this case, installer) as Win 10-compatible, or you need to call a lower-level API that doesn't have the compatibility shims applied. Do reconsider whether you really need to know which version of the OS. Detect *features*, not versions.

Comment: A detailed response in the post you have shared. Thanks a ton @Cody.

Comment: What version of Inno Setup are you using? Make sure you are using the latest one.

Comment: Yes, I am using the latest 5.5.9 version.