# rltGetVersion incorrect ideas as to why?

Tags: windows, vb6

On a windows 10 rtlGetVersion says im using windows XP PRO SP3

I used this link from another stackoverflow post. Explaining why Im having the issue Im currently having to try and solve using GetVersionEx.

[How can a VB 6 app determine if it is running on Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38102565/how-can-a-vb-6-app-determine-if-it-is-running-on-windows-10/38102567#38102567)

i used this exact code on my own to test my own computer before using it in a project. However I am running Windows 10 : version 1903 OS build 18362.295

According to winver and my about.

```
However, using the method described there its returning. 
Windows XP Proffesional SP3 (v5.1.2600) 

Private Const cbCSDVersion As Long = 128 * 2

Private Const STATUS_SUCCESS As Long = 0

Private Const VER_PLATFORM_WIN32s As Long = 0
Private Const VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_WINDOWS As Long = 1
Private Const VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT As Long = 2

Private Const VER_NT_WORKSTATION As Byte = 1
Private Const VER_NT_DOMAIN_CONTROLLER As Byte = 2
Private Const VER_NT_SERVER As Byte = 3

Private Const VER_SUITE_PERSONAL As Integer = &H200

Private Type RTL_OSVERSIONINFOEXW
   dwOSVersionInfoSize As Long
   dwMajorVersion      As Long
   dwMinorVersion      As Long
   dwBuildNumber       As Long
   dwPlatformId        As Long
   szCSDVersion        As String * cbCSDVersion
   wServicePackMajor   As Integer
   wServicePackMinor   As Integer
   wSuiteMask          As Integer
   wProductType        As Byte
   wReserved           As Byte
End Type

Private Declare Function RtlGetVersion Lib "ntdll" _
    (lpVersionInformation As RTL_OSVERSIONINFOEXW) As Long


'==================================================================================
' RealWinVer.bas     by Cody Gray, 2016
' 
' (Freely available for use and modification, provided that credit is given to the
' original author. Including a comment in the code with my name and/or a link to
' this Stack Overflow answer is sufficient.)
'==================================================================================



''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Internal Helper Functions
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Private Function IsWinServerVersion(ByRef ver As RTL_OSVERSIONINFOEXW) As Boolean
   ' There are three documented values for "wProductType".
   ' Two of the values mean that the OS is a server versions,
   ' while the other value signifies a home/workstation version.
   Debug.Assert ver.wProductType = VER_NT_WORKSTATION Or _
                ver.wProductType = VER_NT_DOMAIN_CONTROLLER Or _
                ver.wProductType = VER_NT_SERVER

   IsWinServerVersion = (ver.wProductType <> VER_NT_WORKSTATION)
End Function

Private Function GetWinVerNumber(ByRef ver As RTL_OSVERSIONINFOEXW) As String
   Debug.Assert ver.dwPlatformId = VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT

   GetWinVerNumber = ver.dwMajorVersion & "." & _
                     ver.dwMinorVersion & "." & _
                     ver.dwBuildNumber
End Function

Private Function GetWinSPVerNumber(ByRef ver As RTL_OSVERSIONINFOEXW) As String
   Debug.Assert ver.dwPlatformId = VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT

   If (ver.wServicePackMajor > 0) Then
      If (ver.wServicePackMinor > 0) Then
         GetWinSPVerNumber = "SP" & CStr(ver.wServicePackMajor) & "." & CStr(ver.wServicePackMinor)
         Exit Function
      Else
         GetWinSPVerNumber = "SP" & CStr(ver.wServicePackMajor)
         Exit Function
      End If
   End If
End Function

Private Function GetWinVerName(ByRef ver As RTL_OSVERSIONINFOEXW) As String
   Debug.Assert ver.dwPlatformId = VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT

   Select Case ver.dwMajorVersion
      Case 3
         If IsWinServerVersion(ver) Then
            GetWinVerName = "Windows NT 3.5 Server"
            Exit Function
         Else
            GetWinVerName = "Windows NT 3.5 Workstation"
            Exit Function
         End If
      Case 4
         If IsWinServerVersion(ver) Then
            GetWinVerName = "Windows NT 4.0 Server"
            Exit Function
         Else
            GetWinVerName = "Windows NT 4.0 Workstation"
            Exit Function
         End If
      Case 5
         Select Case ver.dwMinorVersion
            Case 0
               If IsWinServerVersion(ver) Then
                  GetWinVerName = "Windows 2000 Server"
                  Exit Function
               Else
                  GetWinVerName = "Windows 2000 Workstation"
                  Exit Function
               End If
            Case 1
               If (ver.wSuiteMask And VER_SUITE_PERSONAL) Then
                  GetWinVerName = "Windows XP Home Edition"
                  Exit Function
               Else
                  GetWinVerName = "Windows XP Professional"
                  Exit Function
               End If
            Case 2
               If IsWinServerVersion(ver) Then
                  GetWinVerName = "Windows Server 2003"
                  Exit Function
               Else
                  GetWinVerName = "Windows XP 64-bit Edition"
                  Exit Function
               End If
            Case Else
               Debug.Assert False
         End Select
      Case 6
         Select Case ver.dwMinorVersion
            Case 0
               If IsWinServerVersion(ver) Then
                  GetWinVerName = "Windows Server 2008"
                  Exit Function
               Else
                  GetWinVerName = "Windows Vista"
                  Exit Function
               End If
            Case 1
               If IsWinServerVersion(ver) Then
                  GetWinVerName = "Windows Server 2008 R2"
                  Exit Function
               Else
                  GetWinVerName = "Windows 7"
                  Exit Function
               End If
            Case 2
               If IsWinServerVersion(ver) Then
                  GetWinVerName = "Windows Server 2012"
                  Exit Function
               Else
                  GetWinVerName = "Windows 8"
                  Exit Function
               End If
            Case 3
               If IsWinServerVersion(ver) Then
                  GetWinVerName = "Windows Server 2012 R2"
                  Exit Function
               Else
                  GetWinVerName = "Windows 8.1"
                  Exit Function
               End If
            Case Else
               Debug.Assert False
         End Select
      Case 10
         If IsWinServerVersion(ver) Then
            GetWinVerName = "Windows Server 2016"
            Exit Function
         Else
            GetWinVerName = "Windows 10"
            Exit Function
         End If
      Case Else
         Debug.Assert False
   End Select

   GetWinVerName = "Unrecognized Version"
End Function




''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Public Functions
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

' Returns a string that contains the name of the underlying version of Windows,
' the major version of the most recently installed service pack, and the actual
' version number (in "Major.Minor.Build" format).
'
' For example: "Windows Server 2003 SP2 (v5.2.3790)" or
'              "Windows 10 (v10.0.14342)"
'
' This function returns the *real* Windows version, and works correctly on all
' operating systems, including Windows 10, regardless of whether or not the
' application includes a manifest. It calls the native NT version-info function
' directly in order to bypass compatibility shims that would otherwise lie to
' you about the real version number.
Public Function GetActualWindowsVersion() As String
   Dim ver As RTL_OSVERSIONINFOEXW
   ver.dwOSVersionInfoSize = Len(ver)

   If (RtlGetVersion(ver) <> STATUS_SUCCESS) Then
      GetActualWindowsVersion = "Failed to retrieve Windows version"
   End If

   ' The following version-parsing logic assumes that the operating system
   ' is some version of Windows NT. This assumption will be true if you
   ' are running any version of Windows released in the past 15 years,
   ' including several that were released before that.
   Debug.Assert ver.dwPlatformId = VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT

   GetActualWindowsVersion = GetWinVerName(ver) & " " & GetWinSPVerNumber(ver) & _
                             " (v" & GetWinVerNumber(ver) & ")"
End Function


Private Sub Main()
    On Error Resume Next


    Debug.Print "Getting OS system"
    Debug.Print "Real OS: " & GetActualWindowsVersion


End Sub
```

Thoughts and ideas on how I can resolve this? Or did I basically need to find another method?

Answer (score 1):

Found my issue. And honestly I would not have guessed it. Nor do I know why it works like this.

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?846709-OS-Version-information-class&highlight=

From Elroy:

> Interestingly, it seems to circumvent any compatibility shims when
>   running compiled. However, it doesn't circumvent the shims when
>   executing from the IDE. In other words, if you have compatibility
>   shims set for the VB6.EXE, it'll report whatever those shims say
>   rather than the true OS.