# Differentiating between windows server 2016 and 2019

Tags: windows, vb6

Summary of what im Trying to do. Use `rtlGetVersion` to *determine the difference between windows server 2016 and 2019* using the version number such as 1803/1809 and not the latest release build version number.

---

Im fixing our old code that use GetVersionEx over to rltGetVersion. Most of the code was written so it was just a matter of implementing it. Using this link. [How can a VB 6 app determine if it is running on Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38102565/how-can-a-vb-6-app-determine-if-it-is-running-on-windows-10/38102567#38102567)

The issue is windows server 2016 and 19 have the same fields so determinning which one it is cant be done with this setup. Using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_Windows_versions. I know windows 2016 have version 1803 and 2019 have version 1809.

The problem I run into is using rtlGetVersion creates a struct like so. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/ns-wdm-_osversioninfoexw

And the build number is as close as I can seem to get. But that changes. I was wondering if someone knows a way to get the build version and not the build number if that makes sense.

This is the code used from the first link.

```
'==================================================================================
' RealWinVer.bas     by Cody Gray, 2016
' 
' (Freely available for use and modification, provided that credit is given to the
' original author. Including a comment in the code with my name and/or a link to
' this Stack Overflow answer is sufficient.)
'==================================================================================

Option Explicit

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Windows SDK Constants, Types, & Functions
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Private Const cbCSDVersion As Long = 128 * 2

Private Const STATUS_SUCCESS As Long = 0

Private Const VER_PLATFORM_WIN32s As Long        = 0
Private Const VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_WINDOWS As Long = 1
Private Const VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT As Long      = 2

Private Const VER_NT_WORKSTATION As Byte       = 1
Private Const VER_NT_DOMAIN_CONTROLLER As Byte = 2
Private Const VER_NT_SERVER As Byte            = 3

Private Const VER_SUITE_PERSONAL As Integer = &H200

Private Type RTL_OSVERSIONINFOEXW
   dwOSVersionInfoSize As Long
   dwMajorVersion      As Long
   dwMinorVersion      As Long
   dwBuildNumber       As Long
   dwPlatformId        As Long
   szCSDVersion        As String * cbCSDVersion
   wServicePackMajor   As Integer
   wServicePackMinor   As Integer
   wSuiteMask          As Integer
   wProductType        As Byte
   wReserved           As Byte
End Type

Private Declare Function RtlGetVersion Lib "ntdll" _
    (lpVersionInformation As RTL_OSVERSIONINFOEXW) As Long


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Internal Helper Functions
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Private Function IsWinServerVersion(ByRef ver As RTL_OSVERSIONINFOEXW) As Boolean
   ' There are three documented values for "wProductType".
   ' Two of the values mean that the OS is a server versions,
   ' while the other value signifies a home/workstation version.
   Debug.Assert ver.wProductType = VER_NT_WORKSTATION Or _
                ver.wProductType = VER_NT_DOMAIN_CONTROLLER Or _
                ver.wProductType = VER_NT_SERVER

   IsWinServerVersion = (ver.wProductType <> VER_NT_WORKSTATION)
End Function

Private Function GetWinVerNumber(ByRef ver As RTL_OSVERSIONINFOEXW) As String
   Debug.Assert ver.dwPlatformId = VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT

   GetWinVerNumber = ver.dwMajorVersion & "." & _
                     ver.dwMinorVersion & "." & _
                     ver.dwBuildNumber
End Function

Private Function GetWinSPVerNumber(ByRef ver As RTL_OSVERSIONINFOEXW) As String
   Debug.Assert ver.dwPlatformId = VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT

   If (ver.wServicePackMajor > 0) Then
      If (ver.wServicePackMinor > 0) Then
         GetWinSPVerNumber = "SP" & CStr(ver.wServicePackMajor) & "." & CStr(ver.wServicePackMinor)
         Exit Function
      Else
         GetWinSPVerNumber = "SP" & CStr(ver.wServicePackMajor)
         Exit Function
      End If
   End If
End Function

Private Function GetWinVerName(ByRef ver As RTL_OSVERSIONINFOEXW) As String
   Debug.Assert ver.dwPlatformId = VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT

   Select Case ver.dwMajorVersion
      Case 3
         If IsWinServerVersion(ver) Then
            GetWinVerName = "Windows NT 3.5 Server"
            Exit Function
         Else
            GetWinVerName = "Windows NT 3.5 Workstation"
            Exit Function
         End If
      Case 4
         If IsWinServerVersion(ver) Then
            GetWinVerName = "Windows NT 4.0 Server"
            Exit Function
         Else
            GetWinVerName = "Windows NT 4.0 Workstation"
            Exit Function
         End If
      Case 5
         Select Case ver.dwMinorVersion
            Case 0
               If IsWinServerVersion(ver) Then
                  GetWinVerName = "Windows 2000 Server"
                  Exit Function
               Else
                  GetWinVerName = "Windows 2000 Workstation"
                  Exit Function
               End If
            Case 1
               If (ver.wSuiteMask And VER_SUITE_PERSONAL) Then
                  GetWinVerName = "Windows XP Home Edition"
                  Exit Function
               Else
                  GetWinVerName = "Windows XP Professional"
                  Exit Function
               End If
            Case 2
               If IsWinServerVersion(ver) Then
                  GetWinVerName = "Windows Server 2003"
                  Exit Function
               Else
                  GetWinVerName = "Windows XP 64-bit Edition"
                  Exit Function
               End If
            Case Else
               Debug.Assert False
         End Select
      Case 6
         Select Case ver.dwMinorVersion
            Case 0
               If IsWinServerVersion(ver) Then
                  GetWinVerName = "Windows Server 2008"
                  Exit Function
               Else
                  GetWinVerName = "Windows Vista"
                  Exit Function
               End If
            Case 1
               If IsWinServerVersion(ver) Then
                  GetWinVerName = "Windows Server 2008 R2"
                  Exit Function
               Else
                  GetWinVerName = "Windows 7"
                  Exit Function
               End If
            Case 2
               If IsWinServerVersion(ver) Then
                  GetWinVerName = "Windows Server 2012"
                  Exit Function
               Else
                  GetWinVerName = "Windows 8"
                  Exit Function
               End If
            Case 3
               If IsWinServerVersion(ver) Then
                  GetWinVerName = "Windows Server 2012 R2"
                  Exit Function
               Else
                  GetWinVerName = "Windows 8.1"
                  Exit Function
               End If
            Case Else
               Debug.Assert False
         End Select
      Case 10
         If IsWinServerVersion(ver) Then
            GetWinVerName = "Windows Server 2016"
            Exit Function
         Else
            GetWinVerName = "Windows 10"
            Exit Function
         End If
      Case Else
         Debug.Assert False
   End Select

   GetWinVerName = "Unrecognized Version"
End Function


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Public Functions
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

' Returns a string that contains the name of the underlying version of Windows,
' the major version of the most recently installed service pack, and the actual
' version number (in "Major.Minor.Build" format).
'
' For example: "Windows Server 2003 SP2 (v5.2.3790)" or
'              "Windows 10 (v10.0.14342)"
'
' This function returns the *real* Windows version, and works correctly on all
' operating systems, including Windows 10, regardless of whether or not the
' application includes a manifest. It calls the native NT version-info function
' directly in order to bypass compatibility shims that would otherwise lie to
' you about the real version number.
Public Function GetActualWindowsVersion() As String
   Dim ver As RTL_OSVERSIONINFOEXW
   ver.dwOSVersionInfoSize = Len(ver)

   If (RtlGetVersion(ver) <> STATUS_SUCCESS) Then
      GetActualWindowsVersion = "Failed to retrieve Windows version"
   End If

   ' The following version-parsing logic assumes that the operating system
   ' is some version of Windows NT. This assumption will be true if you
   ' are running any version of Windows released in the past 15 years,
   ' including several that were released before that.
   Debug.Assert ver.dwPlatformId = VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT

   GetActualWindowsVersion = GetWinVerName(ver) & " " & GetWinSPVerNumber(ver) & _
                             " (v" & GetWinVerNumber(ver) & ")"
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just compare the build number and that will tell you what Windows 10 version it is. The build number is all you have to go off, there is no way to get the "version" string from Windows 10. Windows Server 2019 will have a build number greater than or equal to 17623, anything with a smaller build number will be Windows Server 2016.

Comment: Did you mean 17763? Also, what if there are updates to Windows Server 2016 later on. Will the build number of Windows 2016 be then greater than 17763?